# which is better way to edit RLIMIT_NPROC value

Tags: c, linux, limits, linux-capabilities, setrlimit

My application creates per connection thread . Application is ruinng under the non-zero user id and Sometimes number of threads surpasses default value 1024 . I want to edit this number  so I have few options

run as root [very bad idea and also have to compromise with securty ,so dropping it]

run under underprivilaged user use ***setcap*** and give capability **CAP_SYS_RESOURCE** . then I can add code im my program

```
      struct rlimit rlp; /* will initilize this later with values of nprocs(maximum number of desired threads)*/
      setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &rlp);
      /*RLIMIT_NPROC
      *The maximum number of processes (or, more precisely on Linux, threads) that can      
      * created for the real user ID of the
      *calling process.  Upon encountering this limit, fork(2) fails with the error
      *EAGAIN. */
```

Other thing is editing */etc/securitylimits.conf*  where simply I can make entry for the development user and can put lines e.g.

```
            @devuser        hard    nproc           20000
            @devuser        soft    nproc           10000
```

where 10k is enough .So being litle reluctant in chaning source code should I proceed with last option . And I am more curios to know what is more robust and standars approach.

seeking your opinions , and thank you in advance :)

PS: What will happen if a single process will be served with more than 1k threads . ofcource i have 32GB of Ram also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I believe you are wrong in having nearly a thousand threads. Threads are quite costly, and it is usually not reasonable to have so much of them. I would suggest having a few dozen threads at most (unless you run on a very costly super-computer).

You could have some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). Then a single thread can deal with many thousands of connections. Read about the [C10K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) and [epoll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll). Consider using some event libraries like [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) etc...

You could start your application as root (perhaps by using [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques), set-up the required resources (in particular, opening privileged TCP/IP ports), and change the user with [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html)

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)...

You could also wrap your application around a tiny setuid C program which increase the limits using  [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html), change the user with `setreuid`, and at last [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) your real program.

Comment: Thanks @Basile , Actually the currunt design is like this and in next rev we will change  it . but till then we want to keep it running .. yes not running on super computer but it is having enough resource . setuid then setruid is great option . But due to reluctancy in changing code for now i have edited /etc/security/limit.conf file ..